# How to judge scroll triggered by mouse wheel or program(like scrollIntoView) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a page to display article and article directory structures. When i clicked on title in article directory structure, I used scrollIntoView to make article scroll and display it's content. At the same time, I used addEventListener to listen article content, if view scrolled, i should make it's directory structure active.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEbIw.png)

Comment: Could you add some code and perhaps a working link?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.